# Getting selected items from a Tkinter listbox without using a listbox bind

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, listbox

I have 2 listboxes (which are connected so that items can move from one to the other) and at the end I would like to get all the entries in the second listbox by using a 'Ok' button (or simply closing the frame). I could add/remove values to a list every time an item is selected (as shown in the commented section of the code below) but I would rather have a single line of code along the lines of `[master.selected.get(idx) for idx in master.selected.curselection()]` in the `close` function but I am unable to get it working.

Code:

```
def measurementPopup(self,master):
    self.chargeCarrier = StringVar()
    self.massModifiers = StringVar()
    self.chargeCarrier.set("[M+xH]")

    def onselect1(evt):
        w = evt.widget
        index = int(w.curselection()[0])
        value = w.get(index)
        # My Dirty fix -> Here I could enter the selected value to a buffer list (to be returned in the ok function).
        master.selected.insert(END,value)
        master.avail.delete(index)

    def onselect2(evt):
        w = evt.widget
        index = int(w.curselection()[0])
        value = w.get(index)
        # My Dirty fix -> Here I could remove the selected value from a buffer list (to be returned in the ok function).
        master.selected.delete(index)
        master.avail.insert(END,value)

    def close(self):
        # Here I would return the buffer list and close the window
        master.measurementWindow = 0
        top.destroy()

    if master.measurementWindow == 1:
        return

    master.measurementWindow = 1
    top = self.top = Toplevel()
    top.protocol( "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: close(self))
    self.charge = Label(top, text = "Charge", width = 10)
    self.charge.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
    self.min = Label(top, text = "Min", width = 5)
    self.min.grid(row=0, column = 1, sticky = W)
    self.minCharge = Spinbox(top, from_= 1, to = 3, width = 5)
    self.minCharge.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)
    self.max = Label(top, text = "Max", width = 5)
    self.max.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W)                  
    self.maxCharge = Spinbox(top, from_ = 1, to=3, width=5)
    self.maxCharge.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W)
    self.chargeCarrier = OptionMenu(top, self.chargeCarrier, "[M+xH]", "[M+xNa]")
    self.chargeCarrier.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = W)
    self.availMass = Label(top, text = "Available")
    self.availMass.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
    self.selectMass = Label(top, text = "Selected")
    self.selectMass.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = W)
    self.massMod = Label(top, text = "Mass Mods")
    self.massMod.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
    self.avail = Listbox(top)
    for i in UNITS:
        if BLOCKS[i]['available'] == 1:
            self.avail.insert(END,BLOCKS[i]['human_readable_name'])
    self.avail.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
    self.avail.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',onselect1)
    self.selected = Listbox(top)
    self.selected.grid(row = 2, column = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
    self.selected.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',onselect2)
    self.ok = Button(top,text = 'Ok',command = lambda: close(self))
    self.ok.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

I have tried to use the following small snippet in the close function:

```
        values = [master.selected.get(idx) for idx in master.selected.curselection()]
        print ', '.join(values)
```

However, the `for` segment doesn't return anything. I would expect that this is due to the fact that nothing is actually selected but that I would need something opposite, along the lines of `master.selected.allitems()` (if it exists and if I understand it correctly).

**Summary**

How would one get all the items in 1 specific listbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.get()` function for the `Listbox` widget allows you to specify a range of items, which can be specified as `0` to `END` to return a tuple of all the items.

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
l = Listbox(root, width = 15)
l.pack()
l.insert(END, "Hello")
l.insert(END, "world")
l.insert(END, "here")
l.insert(END, "is")
l.insert(END, "an")
l.insert(END, "example")

def close():
    global l, root
    items = l.get(0, END)
    print(items)
    root.destroy()

b = Button(root, text = "OK", command = close).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps, if it's not what you were looking for let me know in a comment and I can try expand my answer.